# How to add object again after filtering array with non-null object

Tags: java, arrays, object, null

I am building a classical Nim game **using only the array**, and I found there is a bug after testing. If I successfully create a player, I'll assign a new object to the array. However, when removing the player in the array, I filter the array with non-null objects because I have other functions such as `editplayer`, `displayplayer` to iterate the entire array without `NullPointerException`.

And there is a chance that this happens: `addplayer` → `removeplayer` → `addplayer`. It means I'll always get `IndexOutOfBound` when I try to assign a new object to the array already full of the non-null objects.

I've searched for all the information I could, but there is no such discussion about this. Is there any way to avoid both `NullPointerException` and `IndexOutOfBound` at the same time?

Here is related code `Nimsys`:

```
public class Nimsys {

public static void addPlayer(String [] name) {
    if (name != null && name.length == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getCounter(); i++) {
            String userCheck = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName();
            if (userCheck.contains(name[0])) {
                System.out.println("The player already exists.\n");// Test if player has been created
                return;
            }
        }
        NimPlayer.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
        System.out.println("The player has been created.");
        return;
    } 
    System.out.println("Not Valid! Please enter again!");   
}

public static void searchAndRemovePlayer(String user) {
    NimPlayer [] playerList = NimPlayer.getPlayer();
    for (int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        String userName =playerList[i].getUserName().trim();
        if (userName.equals(user)) {
            playerList[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Remove successfully!");
            NimPlayer.setPlayerList(playerList);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The player does not exist.\n");

}
}
```

Here is part of `NimPlayer` class:

```
public class NimPlayer {
private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;
private int score;
private int gamePlayed;

private static int counter;
private static final int SIZE = 10;
private static NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[SIZE]; // set an array here


//define NimPlayer data type
public NimPlayer(String userName, String surName, String givenName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = surName;
    this.givenName = givenName;

}
// create new data using NimPlayer data type
public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    if (counter < SIZE) {
        playerList[counter++] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
    }
}
public static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
public static NimPlayer [] getPlayer() {      
    return playerList;
}
public static void setPlayerList(NimPlayer [] newplayerList) {
    playerList = Arrays.stream(newplayerList).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(NimPlayer[]::new);
    counter = playerList.length;  //update the counter
}
    //setters and getters of the other variables
}
```

Comment: Why don't you update the variable `SIZE` too when the `playerList` being bigger?

Comment: If I update the `SIZE` as well, it means there will always be a new null object in the array. Thus, when I use `displayplayer` or `editplayer` function to iterate the entire array, there will be `NullPointerException`.

Comment: And since the `setPlayerList` is a static method, I cannot make it increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of explaining about these exceptions, I recommend you go through the documentation of [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) and [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). It is not a big deal to handle these exceptions when they occur. However, the most important thing is to prevent them i.e. you should understand what is the root cause and work on them. We all know, **"Prevention is better than cure."**.
2. You should always try to hide as much information from the class as is possible e.g. you already have a `public static void createPlayer` then, why have you created a `public` constructor? Why have you created a `public` getter for `counter` which is meant to be used only internally in the class, `NimPlayer`?
3. Instead of exposing the `playerList` to be set from outside, you should remove its `public` setter and create `public static void removePlayer` similar to `public static void createPlayer`.

On a **side note** (because it won't affect the execution of the program), the name of an identifier should be self-explanatory e.g. your `getPlayer` method should be named as `getPlayerList` as it is returning the `playerList`, not a single player.

Given below is the code incorporating these comments:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

class NimPlayer {
    private String userName;
    private String familyName;
    private String givenName;
    private int score;
    private int gamePlayed;

    private static int counter;
    private static final int SIZE = 10;
    private static NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[SIZE];

    private NimPlayer(String userName, String surName, String givenName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.familyName = surName;
        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
        if (counter < SIZE) {
            playerList[counter++] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
        }
    }

    public static void removePlayer(NimPlayer player) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if (playerList[i] != null && playerList[i].getUserName().equals(player.getUserName())) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = i; j < playerList.length - 1; j++) {
            playerList[j] = playerList[j + 1];
        }
        counter--;
    }

    public static NimPlayer[] getPlayerList() {
        return Arrays.stream(playerList).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(NimPlayer[]::new);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return userName + " " + familyName + " " + givenName;
    }
}

class NimSys {

    public static void addPlayer(String[] name) {
        if (name != null && name.length == 3) {
            NimPlayer[] playerList = NimPlayer.getPlayerList();
            for (int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
                String userCheck = playerList[i].getUserName();
                if (userCheck.contains(name[0])) {
                    System.out.println("The player, " + name[0] + " already exists.\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
            NimPlayer.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
            System.out.println("The player, " + name[0] + "  has been created.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Not Valid! Please enter again!");
    }

    public static void searchAndRemovePlayer(String user) {
        NimPlayer[] playerList = NimPlayer.getPlayerList();
        for (int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
            String userName = playerList[i].getUserName().trim();
            if (userName.equals(user)) {
                NimPlayer.removePlayer(playerList[i]);
                System.out.println("The player, " + user + " removed successfully!");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The player, " + user + "  does not exist.\n");
    }

    public static void displayPlayerList() {
        NimPlayer[] playerList = NimPlayer.getPlayerList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (NimPlayer player : playerList) {
            sb.append(player.getUserName()).append(" ").append(player.getFamilyName()).append(" ")
                    .append(player.getGivenName()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Harry", "Potter", "Harry" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.searchAndRemovePlayer("Harry");
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Manny", "Richard", "Canty" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Arvind", "Kumar", "Avinash" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.searchAndRemovePlayer("Manny");
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Ken", "Ken", "Thompson" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.searchAndRemovePlayer("Ken");
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Ken", "Ken", "Thompson" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.searchAndRemovePlayer("Ken");
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();

        NimSys.addPlayer(new String[] { "Ken", "Ken", "Thompson" });
        NimSys.displayPlayerList();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The player, Harry  has been created.
Harry Potter Harry

The player, Harry removed successfully!

The player, Manny  has been created.
Manny Richard Canty

The player, Arvind  has been created.
Manny Richard Canty
Arvind Kumar Avinash

The player, Manny removed successfully!
Arvind Kumar Avinash

The player, Ken  has been created.
Arvind Kumar Avinash
Ken Ken Thompson

The player, Ken removed successfully!
Arvind Kumar Avinash

The player, Ken  has been created.
Arvind Kumar Avinash
Ken Ken Thompson

The player, Ken removed successfully!
Arvind Kumar Avinash

The player, Ken  has been created.
Arvind Kumar Avinash
Ken Ken Thompson
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. There will be an `IndexOutOfBound` if add the player first, then remove the same player, and again add the same player in. @Arvind

Comment: `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` for creating back the same player.

Comment: If I do this, add the player, remove the same player, and add another player. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` again.

Comment: @Woden - I've corrected the problem and also posted some new test results. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: I've tested it, it's CLEAR. But I cannot figure out what's the meaning of modified code, though. It seems a tricky bug. @Arvind

Comment: Great! `I cannot figure out what's the meaning of modified code` - what's it and where have you seen it?

Comment: I know the `filter` should be put in the getter in order to fill the null object before being called. However, I don't know why should I put the `removeplayer` method in the `NimPlayer` class? And I have no idea about the management of the `counter` and the array length.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer as well, you should not expose the whole `playerList` outside the `NimPlayer` class. Instead of that, you should just expose the valid operations (e.g. `createPlayer`, `removePlayer` etc.) on `playerList` . In fact, I was going to tell you to write some more methods (e.g. `searchPlayer`) like these so that you can remove `getPlayerList` as well. As per the OOP principles, the access should be as restrictive as possible. Managing `counter` is straight forward i.e. increase it in  `createPlayer` and decrease it in `removePlayer`.

Comment: Good day, sir. I've finished the project. And I've learned the UML, which converts the source code to the diagram. Therefore, I have another question about coding. Is it a good practice to design the UML first, then coding? @Arvind

Comment: Good morning, Woden! It's a good practice to draw the UML diagrams first before coding. It's like preparing the blueprint of the things before you jump into coding. For further comment, I need to know the name of the UML tool that you are using.

Comment: I am using eclipse and VsCode as IDE, but it seems only the eclipse can convert the source code to the class diagrams.

Comment: In eclipse, I use objectAid. @Arvind

Comment: Alright...It's a very good tool...you can learn a lot from the generated diagrams...once you are confident, you can start the other way round (i.e. first create UML diagrams and then write code). Once you are familiar with UML, you can also check https://plantuml.com/

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: "Is there any way to avoid both NullPointerException and IndexOutOfBound at the same time?"

Yes, you can do that by using the following two things.

First, you can get the length of the array using its `length` property. `length` is the number of elements in the array (including those whose value is `null`).  With that information you should never be indexing out of bounds (as long as you're not writing concurrent code that modifies the array's length).

Secondly, you need to check what you take out of the array to see if it is null. You can just do that with an if statement.

Here's what that would look like:

```
// create an array with 5 elements. 0, 2, and 4 are null. 1 and 3 are not null.
String[] myArray = new String[5];
myArray[1] = "abc ";
myArray[3] = "def";

// myArray.length will be '5'
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  String value = myArray[i];

  if (value != null) {
    // prints "ABC DEF" and doesn't result in a NullPointer
    System.out.print(value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

So in your case:

```
public static void addPlayer(String [] name) {
    if (name != null && name.length == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getPlayer().length; i++) {
            NimPlayer player = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i];

            if (player != null && player.getUserName().contains(name[0]))
                System.out.println("The player already exists.\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        NimPlayer.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
        System.out.println("The player has been created.");
        return;
    } 
    System.out.println("Not Valid! Please enter again!");   
}
```

And just to add. In object oriented programming you generally want to follow the principle of encapsulation - so you probably want to move the methods in NimSys into NimPlayer since they operate on the data in NimPlayer.

I'm guessing you're new to Java and programming. Good luck learning!

Comment: yes, I am new to Java and programming. Thank you for answering my question. The `counter` is for recording the player in the `playerList` when every time I create a new player object. @phonaputer

Comment: My mistake about the counter part. I took that out of my answer.

Comment: Because I used the array from another class `NimPlayer`, I cannot resolve the `length` here in the `Nimsys` class.

Comment: Since getPlayer() returns an array you can access .length on the array which it returns.